# Change only the false properties of an bool Eval

Tags: asp.net, boolean, eval

I am trying to change only the false property of this bool instead of having to change booth the true and the false. I am using a customer style for the rest of the page so I want to leave the true value to its default but change the false value to gray.

`BackColor='<%# (bool)Eval("active") ? System.Drawing.Color.Green :      System.Drawing.Color.Gray %>'`

I just want to have the false be Gray, and the true to stay the default.

Comment: Why not just set it to TRUE?

Comment: What do you mean by setting it true? Active = true, Inactive = false. Are you saying why not just change inactive to being true instead? I guess there is a better way to write this expression if I am only changing false I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tertiary condition return value if either false or true. So if you have to return a value.

You can set a property of default color in aspx.cs page which will be returned if active is true. Alternatively you can write a function which return return value in aspx.cs page and call it by passing active from aspx page.

Hope it help.